# CSS pop-up menu not working with ASP Master Page

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I've drawn a sketch that helps illustrate the situation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZLbY.png

We are using a Master Page. The top of the screen has a header, including a "Profile" menu at the top-right corner. (Account settings, logout button, etc.) If you hover over the menu, it expands downwards.

Beneath the header is the main content filled by the Master Page.

**The issue:** When hovering over the Profile menu, it expands downwards over top of the main content. If the mouse stays within the header, things work fine. But as soon as they travel into the Main Content area, the "hover" stops and the menu goes away. This makes it very difficult to click anything in the Profile menu.

**What I've tried:** Figuring this might be an overlap issue (Main content overlapping Profile menu), I played with the z-index, hoping to put the Profile menu on top. Unfortunately this seemed to have no impact.

Tried shrinking the main content to only be 10px wide. This removed the overlap. The issue didn't occur during this test, confirming it's related to the overlap.

Also tried rebuilding the page, and stripping it down to its barebones. This didn't fix it, unfortunately.

Below is the barebones HTML/CSS.

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.master.cs" Inherits="TestProject.Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Title</title>

    <style>
.profile-wrapper {
    width:200px;
}
.profile-wrapper::after {
    content: &#39;&#39;;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    border-color: #333 transparent transparent;
    border-width: 6px;
    border-style: solid;
}
.profile-wrapper::before {
    content: &#39;&#39;;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    border-color: #eee transparent transparent;
    border-width: 6px;
    border-style: solid;
}
.profile-wrapper:hover::after {
    border-color: #111 transparent transparent; 
}

.profile {
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-radius:3px;
    z-index:100;
}
.profile:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.profile .name {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:26px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
.profile .name:hover {
    color:#0088cc;
}
.profile img {
    width:25px;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #111;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}

/* hide menu */
.menu {
    display:none;
    clear:both;
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
}
.menu li {
    font-size:12px;
    margin:0;
  padding: 10px 4px;
}
.menu li a {
    color:#555;
}
.menu li:hover &gt; a{
    color:#eee;
}

.menu li:hover{
    border-left: 1px solid #111;
  border-right: 1px solid #222;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
  border-top: 1px solid #111;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

/* hover profile show menu */
.profile:hover .menu {
    display:block;
}
    </style>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="HeaderBar" style="background-color:#DDDDDD; z-index: 100;">
            <a href="Home.aspx">
                <asp:Image ID="LogoImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Logo.png" style="margin-top: 4px; width: 285px"/>
            </a>
            <div style="right: 14px; top: 10px; position: absolute">
                <div class="profile-wrapper">
                    <!-- user profile -->
                    <div class="profile">
                        Profile
                    
                        <!-- more menu -->
                        <ul class="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
                            <li><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Logout</asp:LinkButton></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="MainContent" style="left:260px; top:50px; position:absolute; width: calc(100% - 260px - 20px); z-index: 50;">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand why this worked, but setting the z-index of the main content to -50 resolved the issue.

Previously I used 50 for the main content and 100 for the menu. In my head this should have worked, but it didn't.

But using -50 and 100 worked.